# Find the count of occurrences of a substring within a string in php

Tags: php, email, newline, substr

I have a string say

```
$result = \nHey there!Listen\n\n===\n\nLife is one\n\n===\n\nBut cs is 1.6ok\n\n===\n\nI hope you got what i wanna say\n\nSpeech finished\n\n===\n
```

Now I want to

1. Find the no of occurences of `\n` in the above string. I have used the below function but it outputs nothing :

   ```
   substr_count($result,"\n");
   ```
2. I want to email `$result` as the Email-body , but `\n` characters are appearining as it is. 
   Anyway out there, that I can get rid of these `\n` characters and they are actually replaced by a new line in email subject ?

Comment: This isn't valid PHP, you need some kind of quotation - please post a working minimal example!

Comment: Please try with this - substr_count($result,"\\n"); Its giving count as 18.

Comment: Answer to first and second part of your question http://codepad.viper-7.com/4yzadc

Comment: Works fine here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/JidBIW

Comment: Most likely OP is using `'` instead of `"` and so the `\n` don't get interpreted properly.

Comment: That would be my guess, but since no quotes were provided.... :P

Comment: Works also with heredoc http://codepad.viper-7.com/GpuATL

Comment: Thanks Prava.
adding "\\n" worked out :) 

Can any one answer my 2nd part of the question ?

Why \n aint working as newline while sending emails  :(

Comment: use `str_replace("\n","<br>",$result)` to convert `\n` into newline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$result = str_replace("\n", chr(13), $result );

I replaced all the \n characters by chr(13) that is interpreted as enter .

So it worked out for me  :)